# TYPE_NOTIFICATION with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to use simple notification sound as the sound in my app. But I just can't get it to work. There's no sound at all when I use RingManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION. I should mention that when I use TYPE_ALARM or TYPE_RINGTONE (or TYPE_ALL = it is TYPE_RINGTONE in my mobile phone) it works. I tried also with setVolume(), but no results.

When I send message to myself at this moment (from another phone) I can hear the notification sound.

Some people tried to help me but it is still not solved. Maybe somebody can give me the simplest project for eclipse that I can check if it works? Maybe it's just something wrong with my mobile phone? I have Samsung Galaxy S2.

Here's my code. What do I do wrong? Or what else should I check?

```
Uri _sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri( RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION ); 
// _sound.toString() returns "content://settings/system/notification_sound"

// this doesn't work either
// Uri _sound = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri( getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION );
// _sound.toString() returns "content://media/internal/audio/media/10" if it can help

mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    // doesn't change anything while using TYPE_NOTIFICATION
    // mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f); 

    // tried also mp.setDataSource(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    // but no effect
    mp.setDataSource( getApplicationContext(), _sound );
    mp.setLooping( false );
    mp.prepare();
} catch( IOException e ) {}
mp.start();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use this syntax instead:

```
Uri _sound = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

This works for me.

You can try this too:

```
mp.setDataSource(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
```

Comment: No results. Still no sound at all, works again with TYPE_ALARM and TYPE_RINGTONE inly.

Comment: Stupid question: did you check that the Notification tone isn't set to "silent"? Also if you put Log.d("NotifURI", _sound.toString()); what does it return?

Comment: I can hear the notification sound when somebody sends me a message, I have written this. The code returns me "content://media/internal/audio/media/10"

Comment: Which Settings should I use? I chose the one from android.provider.Settings, but... it still doesn't work, don't know what's going on. Maybe it's something with my phone? Maybe some manifest? I'll try to get my friend's phone soon and check it there. Thanks for interest though. :/

Comment: "import android.provider.Settings;" is correct. You can try with the emulator 4.0.3 have built-in sounds now.

Comment: emulator is a problem too, I have 4.0.3, but when I do long press on my wallpaper it shows only "Live wallpapers", "Pictures" and "Wallpapers", there's nothing about widgets. But in settings I can see that my app has been installed...

Comment: I can find the widget in Settings -> Widget preview, but there's no sound for any type...

Comment: oh my god, the notification sound was just much quietier that other types and I just didn't hear it, haha